# The linear system $|E+nF|$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I'm asking this question with reference to an answer by BlaCa to an old MathOverflow question I saw [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122952/on-a-hirzebruch-surface).

We first recall that the $n$-th Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n$ can be viewed as the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$. It contains a unique irreducible curve $E$ with self-intersection $-n$. Let $F$ be a fiber of $\mathbb{F}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$.

What I'm confused about is the line "The linear system $|E+nF|$ has degree zero on $E$, degree one on $F$ and degree $n$ on $E+F$." What does it mean for a linear system to have some degree over a divisor? Also, how are the degrees zero, one and $n$ deduced?

Moreover, the answer followed up by saying $E$ contracts to a unique singular point whose *hyperplane section is a rational normal curve of degree n*. Why is this a consequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You working over on a surface $\mathbf{F}_n$ so a the divisors $E,F$ are given by (smooth) curves on $\mathbf{F}_n$!
Now what you do is you restrict the divisor $E+ nF$ to $E$ or $F$ and then recall that the associated line bundle to the divisor $E+nF$ becomes after restriction $\mathcal{O}(E+nF)|_E$ or $\mathcal{O}(E+nF)|_F$ and line bundles on curves have a degree (it is just the degree of any non-zero rational section of that line bundle!).
Then use the that $F$ (or $E$ or $E+F$) are effective divisors on $\mathbf{F}_n$ and you have the formula $$\deg(\mathcal{O}(E+nF)|_F)=(E+nF).F$$ which is $(E+nF).F=EF+nF^2=1$ which is what you wanted. Analogously for $E$ and $E+F$!

Comment: Thank you for your computation, I will try to understand. May I know how does it cause $E$ to be mapped to a singular point?

Comment: I don't understand: what singular point? Everything is mapped to $\mathbf{P}^1$ where you don't have any singular points?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the linked post, the *singular* point actually refers to a *single* point, which is the image of $E$. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the linear system has degree zero over $E$.

Comment: Regarding the linked post again, do you know why does the linear system having degree zero on $E$, degree one on $F$, and degree $n$ on $E+F$ imply that $\mathbb{F}_n$ is mapped to a surface in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$?

Comment: you use this linear system to get an embedding into some $\mathbf{P}^{m}$ which works for any ample line bundle. Why $m=n+1$ I don't see on the spot !

Comment: That was the other part that I was confused about too. I suppose the $n+1$ comes from $|E+nF|$ has degree one on $F$ and degree $n$ on $E+nF$ but I can't see the link.

Comment: the degree of a linear system and its dimension are not the same! They are linked by Riemann Roch (at least over curves), which you probably know?

Comment: Alright I will try harder about it, thank you for your time!